# Examples of methods with single string arguments

Tags: ruby

Could someone give me an example of a method that accepts a single string argument. Whilst i appreciate this might seem trivial I am trying to understand how this works in ruby. Would the syntax below be correct.

```
Def method("argument")
  true
end
```

Comment: There's not really such a thing - method declarations contain no type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if it is a string by yourself. You can make use of `is_a?` to see if it is a `String` as Ruby is dynamically typed.

```
def add_watson(f_name)
  f_name << " Watson" if f_name.is_a? String
end
```

Now, calling it

```
puts add_watson("Emma") #=> Emma Watson
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't. First of all, `def` keyword is lowercased. Also, method argument(s) is written like this `def my_method(argument)` and at this point it doesn't check if it's string, in fact, it can accept any object, because Ruby is typed dynamically. If you want to force `String` instance as an argument, you can do it inside of method body:

```
def my_method(argument)
  raise ArgumentError, "argument must be a String" unless argument.is_a? String
  true
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
def method(arg)
   puts "arg"
end
```

You can review some tutorial too

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm

http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/